# How do I writeline before prompt in my while loop? 

Tags: c#, arrays, loops, while-loop

My program collects the number of bottles collected by four rooms. When the user types in quit  at anytime, the program goes out of the while look and shows the outcome of the bottle collection. It then calculates the winning room with the most bottle count.

I have a while loop I dont understand why I cant enter it. To enter the while loop, it will prompt me to enter a number 1-4, as used in my array, and the number of bottles each of the room has collected. If i type quit at anytime, the program will stop recording bottles and spit out the outcome and the winning room with the most bottles.

How do I get "Enter the room number you are in" to show up first before I enter in the bottle count? My problem exists in getBottles()

I think this line cant be used in an array, am i right?

rooms[room - 1] += int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

```
namespace BottleDrive
{
    class BottleDrive
    {
        public int[] rooms;
        public BottleDrive()
        {
            rooms = new int[4];
        }

        static void Main(string[] args) //static is member of class not object
        {
            BottleDrive bD = new BottleDrive();
            bD.getBottles();
            bD.displayBottleCount();
            bD.findWinner();
        }
        public void getBottles()
        {
            string quit = Console.ReadLine();
            while while(quit != "quit")
            {
                int room = int.Parse(quit);

                Console.Write("Bottles collected in room {0}: ", room);
                rooms[room - 1] += int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                Console.Write("Enter the room you're in: ");
            }
        }
        public void findWinner()
        {
            int maxValue = 0;//initiates the winner, contructor starts at 0
            int maxRoomNumber = 0;//initiates the room number that wins
            for (int i = 0; i < rooms.Length; ++i)//This loop goes through the array of rooms (4)
            {
                if (rooms[i] > maxValue)//Makes sure that the maxValue is picked in the array
                {//Looking for room number for the 
                    maxValue = rooms[i];
                    maxRoomNumber = i + 1;
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine("And the Winner is room " + maxRoomNumber + "!!!");
        }
        public void displayBottleCount()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Bottles collected in room one: " + rooms[0]);
            Console.WriteLine("Bottles collected in room two: " + rooms[1]);
            Console.WriteLine("Bottles collected in room three: " + rooms[2]);
            Console.WriteLine("Bottles collected in room four: " + rooms[3]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Make sure your casing matches. `while (quit.ToLower() == "quit")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line:

```
while (quit == "quit")
```

should actually be:

```
while (quit != "quit")
```

Or better yet:

```
while (!quit.Equals("quit", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
```

Which will ignore case for the input. As others have noted, there's more issues with your loop. Try using this for your getBottles function:

```
public void getBottles()
{
    string input;

    do
    {
        Console.Write("Enter the room you're in: (or quit)");
        input = Console.ReadLine();

        int room;
        // doing try parst because the input might be "quit" or other junk
        if (int.TryParse(input, out room))
        {
            Console.Write("Bottles collected in room {0}: ", room);
            // this will fail hard if the input is not of type int
            rooms[room - 1] += int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        }
    } while (!input.Equals("quit", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)); 
}
```

Comment: Thank you, do statement is the way to go, and nest the while after. Fabulous!

Answer (score 4):

```
while (quit == "quit")
```

The above line will only run the loop if quit (what you got from the console) is "quit".

You want:

```
while (quit != "quit")
```

or

```
while (!quit.Equals("quit"))
```

After all that though you are also not actually updating quit inside your loop so once in you will never get out.

You'll need to capture your console.Readline and put it into "quit".

You probably also want to look at [int.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7.aspx) in case people type in a string that isn't quit or a valid integer. TryParse will tell you whether the parse was successful or not rather than throwing an exception.

Answer (score 1):

Should you have `while(quit != "quit")` for the while condition perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
while (!quit.Equals("quit"))
```

Answer (score 0):

The function getBottles() looks very strange. You only enter the while loop when you type "quit". I don't think that this is the behaviour you want.

Comment: Yeah i just mentioned that, I want it to prompt me to enter room number first, and then the bottle that room has collected. getBottles() ,is the format wrong or the code for
rooms[room - 1] += int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); wrong?